# SQL constraint: foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I can't figure out what's wrong with the constraint in the second sql create statement.

```
CREATE TABLE `sd344`.`COURSES` 
(
`Cno` CHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
`Ctitle` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
`Hours` TIME NOT NULL, 
`DeptId` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '13',
 CONSTRAINT COURSPK 
 PRIMARY KEY (Cno)
);

CREATE TABLE `DEPARTMENTS` 
(
`DeptId` INT NOT NULL,
`DeptName` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
`College` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY(DeptId),
 UNIQUE(DeptName),
 CONSTRAINT DEPTFK
 FOREIGN KEY(DeptId) REFERENCES COURSES
 ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

The problem seems to come from

```
CONSTRAINT DEPTFK
FOREIGN KEY(DeptId) REFERENCES COURSES
ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Can anyone please help me figure it out?
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS and error or wrong behavior?

Comment: @LuciaPasarin Why does it matter which DBMS? The [ANSI foreign key syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#Defining_foreign_keys) is fairly clear. Also, I'm guessing it's MySQL due to the backticks

Comment: The DBMS might matter not only because of the syntax but also because of the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've simply attempted to apply the *foreign* key to the wrong table. This should be on `COURSES`

```
FOREIGN KEY (DeptId) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS
```

or

```
FOREIGN KEY (DeptId) REFERENCES DEPARTMENTS (DeptId)
```

Comment: However, how to I add the "ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE" part to it? Thanks

Comment: @user3112318 Same way you did before. You just had the declaration on the wrong table